# How to redirect all requests to index.html with nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

Question: I am trying to redirect all requests to index.html with nginx configuration but it is not working. How can I configure nginx to redirect all requests to index.html?

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  #listen 443; as said in edit 1
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name localhost;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate.key;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

And I am still getting this error in my error log:

> 2023/01/19 07:27:59 [error] 35#35: *6 open()
> "/usr/share/nginx/html/oqy3guq34r" failed (2: No such file or
> directory), client: 10.3.32.1, server: localhost, request: "GET
> /oqy3guq34r HTTP/1.1", host: "myhost.com"

[image: 404 Not Found nginx/1.23.3]

What am I missing in my configuration?

---

Edit

---

To those interested in an answer, in my case it was an openshift configuration that was preventing me from using ssl; When I disable this setting above it works normally.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the configuration across all included files and ensure that the `server` block appears as it is in your question.

Comment: @RichardSmith, I haven't been able to solve it yet but your suggestion is helping me a lot! Thank you very much!